# Gradle not able to detect osdetector plugin

Tags: java, gradle, netty, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using OpenSSL for my Java GRPC project which uses gradle.

I read the [documetation](http://www.grpc.io/docs/guides/auth.html#base-case-no-encryption-or-authentication) which mentions that we should make security settings as mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#transport-security-tls).

I have included the osdetector plugin in the build.gradle file.

But when I build the project, gradle is not able to resolve the osdetector plugin and throwing error

```
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.google.protobuf']
   > Plugin with id 'osdetector' not found.
```

My gradle file is as follows:

```
def neo4jVersion = "2.3.3"

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'com.google.osdetector'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.4.0'
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        // The version of protoc must match protobuf-java. If you don't depend on
        // protobuf-java directly, you will be transitively depending on the
        // protobuf-java version that grpc depends on.
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0-beta-2"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:0.12.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
        }
    }
    generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/src/generated"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-all:0.12.0'
    compile "org.neo4j:neo4j:${neo4jVersion}"
    compile "org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-core:2.0.1"
    compile "org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-http-driver:2.0.1"
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev71-1.22.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'
    compile 'io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:1.1.33.Fork14:' + osdetector.classifier
}
```

The compile dependency alone is getting resolved however.

I think I am missing something basic here. Please let me know the solution.

Updated

Comment: What version of gradle are you using? Google's protobuf plugin requires at least Gradle 12. You can specify the gradle version to use by overriding the `wrapper` task in your build script (see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)). After this change you need to generate the wrapper again with `gradle wrapper` and can build your project with the respective Gradle version now by using `gradlew build` in your project root.

Comment: I'm actually asking for the Gradle version as the first error seems to be `Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.google.protobuf']`...

Comment: Thanks dpr.....the gradle version is distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.9-bin.zip. I changed it to distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-bin.zip. It did not solve the problem though. Please let me know if if this is the right gradle version I was supposed to change to.                                 > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.google.protobuf']
   > Could not create an instance of type com.google.protobuf.gradle.ProtobufSourceDirectorySet_Decorated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

protobuf-gradle-plugin [is not compatible](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/issues/74) with osdetector-gradle-plugin-1.4.0, since that version changed the name of the plugin. Swapping to version osdetector 1.2.1 should fix the problem.

Comment: @DivijeNarasimhachar, did you change the apply plugin declaration from `apply plugin: 'com.google.osdetector'` to `apply plugin: 'osdetector'`? Reading Eric's answer correctly the ID of the plugin was changed in versions > 1.2.1 and the documentation reflects the most recent ID only...

Comment: @dpr : The issue is resolved. Thank you so much for pointing out that. I was using apply plugin: 'com.google.osdetector'. :)

Comment: Hi @Eric I am trying to integrate SSL  for my Android app , I have declared the following in the build.gradle.
apply plugin: 'osdetector'
classpath 'com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.2.1'

I am getting the following error when I am trying to build the gradle

Error:Could not find com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.2.1.
Am I missing something here , I am following the documentation - https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md

Thanks.

Comment: @PraveenPandey, you're probably missing `buildscript { repositories { mavenCentral() } }`. See the [readme](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/README.md) for a nicely formatted version.