# Not able to connect to grpc server from client through SSL

Tags: java, openssl, grpc

In my project using grpc and java,I am using OpenSSL to make a secure connection between Client and server.

I am able to bring the grpc server up successfully.

The documentation [here](http://www.grpc.io/docs/guides/auth.html#base-case-no-encryption-or-authentication) mentions that the client code for a secure channel is this

```
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("myservice.example.com", 443)
    .build();
GreeterGrpc.GreeterStub stub = GreeterGrpc.newStub(channel);
```

I am using the code at client as follows but the below exception is being thrown.

```
    mChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(GrpcConstants.LOCAL_GRPC_CLIENT_IP, GrpcConstants.LOCAL_GRPC_CLIENT_PORT).build();

    mEmployerServicesBlockingStub = EmployerServicesGrpc.newBlockingStub(mChannel);
    mInviteContactsBlockingStub = InviteContactsGrpc.newBlockingStub(mChannel);
```

Exception:

```
Network channel closed
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:431)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:157)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:106)
```

I tried with the following code also:

```
    mChannel = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(GrpcConstants.LOCAL_GRPC_CLIENT_IP, GrpcConstants.LOCAL_GRPC_CLIENT_PORT).sslContext(GrpcSslContexts.forClient().trustManager(file).build()).build();

    mEmployerServicesBlockingStub = EmployerServicesGrpc.newBlockingStub(mChannel);
    mInviteContactsBlockingStub = InviteContactsGrpc.newBlockingStub(mChannel);
```

This is also giving the same exception as above. I just gave a null file reference here.

Please let me know which approach should be used for a GoDaddy certificate.

If it is the first approach, what am I missing.

If it is the second approach, which file am I supposed to use for "roots.pem".

Updated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the exception is cut off a bit at the top. There may also be a causal exception ("Caused by:") that could be helpful. In either case, this may be similar to [another issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1330), where gRPC "misses" the original error and is now just detecting later failures.

Both approaches to Channel creation should work. If you are using a reverse proxy, I would assume the problem is either the server not supporting AES GCM or ALPN (with HTTP/2). You can use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to check for support. For example, Google [supports both](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=google.com&s=2607%3af8b0%3a4005%3a806%3a0%3a0%3a0%3a200e&hideResults=on). If you are contacting a gRPC server directly, I would expect an issue initializing tcnative.

It is probably worth-while to create a GitHub issue to help us in tracking down the true cause.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to make a successful connection using the code that was given for SSL on grpc documentation, giving the client side .crt file on the client code and the private key and the server .crt file on the server side.

Comment: Still there was another problem. The client was neither giving exception nor reaching the server. Somehow the same code for SSL was successful through the grpc-java github example project. The only difference I could see from my project to the grpc-java example implementation is the version of osdetector. I was not able to include osdetector 1.4.0 due to this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160085/gradle-not-able-to-detect-osdetector-plugin). Whereas grpc-java had 1.4.0 and was building successfully using  skipcodegen=true param during gradle build.

Comment: @DivijeNarasimhachar, I don't expect osdetector version to be the problem. The only idea I have is that you are using a wrong SslContext:  `GrpcSslContexts.forClient()` on the server-side, or `GrpcSslContexts.forServer()` on the client-side. That's really hard to notice as a typo and I've heard causes a hang.