# Could not find com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.2.1

Tags: android, grpc

I have been following documentation at the location - https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md
Error:Could not find com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.2.1.
I have searched through net , I am not able to find any solution .
Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99% probability is that the version number `1.2.1` does not exist.

The documentation referenced in your question specifies `1.4.0` everywhere.

Change the version to `1.4.0` and it should resolve if the version number is the problem.

```
compile 'com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.4.0'
```

Comment: Thanks AndroidMechanic , I tried compile 'com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.4.0' , but faced the same issue . as per suggestion from link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160085/gradle-not-able-to-detect-osdetector-plugin/37383151#37383151 I am using 1.2.1.

Comment: did you add `mavenCentral()` under repositories

Comment: This solved the issue . Feeling very stupid to have missed this . Thanks for your time .

Comment: Glad to be of help. Do accept the answer of it solved your problem. Cheers!